# Creating polygon out of very large line feature class using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3

I am trying to create a polygon out of a line feature class in ArcMap 10.3.1.

I have tried using the advanced editing "construct polygons" tool and mesed with the clustering sizes but only get polygons in the very small tight corners of my would be polygon... I have also tried using the "feature class to polygon" tool but have gotten the same results.

I'm assuming at this point that my polygon in the main section is not completely closed and this is why it is happening the way it is. The problem is that I cannot check the topology due to the feature still being classified as a line (or I don't know how, if it is possible) other than visually, which I have tried to do for a few hours now to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Standard or Advanced License you can create a [geodatabase topology](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-topology-toolset.htm) for lines.  For my Road Network I use the Must Not Self-Intersect, Must Not Intersect or Touch Interior, Must Not Have Dangles and Must Be Single Part rules to have the topology indicate lines that overshoot/undershoot other lines and that do not have line ends that meet at every intersection.

You also need a Standard or Advanced license to use the [Extend Line tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/editing/extend-line.htm) in the Editor toolbox.  This tool could be used to close small gaps without setting up a geodatabase topology.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will give that a try. Is it possible to make a geodatabase if I already have my polyline as a complete shapefile?

Comment: You have to create a Feature Dataset inside the file geodatabase first to create a geodatabase topology.  The feature dataset defines the projection of all the data it contains and the projection should be set to match the shapefile.  You can use Export to convert the shapefile to a file geodatabase feature class within a feature dataset or the Feature Class to Feature Class tool can be used to load it into a geodatabase feature class feature dataset.